# how to display total sum of a pie chart using fusion chart in asp

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

is there a way to to show the total sum of pie chart using fusion chart? I have created fusion charts in ASP and all what i am trying to do is to show the total sum values of all the slices of the pie chart. For instance, if i have 3 slices on my pie chart: and each one has these values: 20, 30, 25; so i want to show the total 75 in the sub caption area or on the top of the chart. Is there a way to do this? please help.

```
 public string CreateChart()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT Category, AvgNumbers FROM MyTable";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strXML;
        strXML = "<graph caption='Average Days To Close' subcaption='I want to show here the Total Sum' labelDisplay='auto' useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1'  decimalPrecision='0' showValues='1' enablesmartlabels='0' showlabels='0'  legendAllowDrag='1' numberSuffix=' Days' showLegend='1' pieSliceDepth='45' formatNumberScale='0'>";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            strXML += "<set name='" + reader["Category"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString() + "' />";
        }
        strXML += "</graph>";
        return FusionCharts.RenderChart("/FusionCharts/Pie3D.swf", "ChartID", strXML, "FactorySum", "450", "450", false, false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string strXML;
    int sumAvgNumbers;
    string strXMLTemp;
while (reader.Read())
    {
        strXMLTemp += "<set name='" + reader["Category"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString() + "' />";
        sumAvgNumbers = sumAvgNumbers + Convert.toInt32(reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString());
    }
    strXML = "<graph caption='Average Days To Close' subcaption='"+ sumAvgNumbers +"' labelDisplay='auto' useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1'  decimalPrecision='0' showValues='1' enablesmartlabels='0' showlabels='0'  legendAllowDrag='1' numberSuffix=' Days' showLegend='1' pieSliceDepth='45' formatNumberScale='0'>";
    strXML += strXMLTemp;
```